# Does Django support accessible form errors?

Tags: django, forms, accessibility

I'm developing a Django application and I'm trying to make it as accessible as possible.

According to an accessibility expert on my team, when displaying a form error it is best to give it focus, so screen reader software (i.e. JAWS) will read the page starting at that point instead of reading the whole page from the top.

Does Django provide a way to do this?  The "errorlist" class renders errors in a bold red font but it doesn't do much else that I can see.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035288/getting-a-list-of-errors-in-a-django-form

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, Django can do anything HTML can do--it's always possible to render your page with whatever markup you want.

That said, the default output for errors, as you've mentioned, does not automatically grab focus.