# How do I change the Django form.errors display text?

Tags: django, django-forms

[I want to remove the circled bit from being displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9N32.png) How would I be able to do this?

```
{% if form.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"
       role="alert">
      <p class="m-0">{{ form.errors }}</p>
    <button type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="alert"
            aria-label="Close">
    </button>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

This always displays

- property where the error is found

  - error message
  - error message ...

I want to remove the property where the error is found. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Django 4.0 or high

```
                {%  if form.errors  %}
                    {% for error in form.errors.as_data.values %}
                        {% for data in error.0 %}
                            {{ data }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django Form has two error handlers:

- `Form.errors` are field errors. By default, a dict of key "field name" : value "field errors"
- `Form.non_field_errors` are general errors that have no relation to a field name, mainly errors from the Form.clean(..) method.

So you are trying to do an anti-pattern and a distraction to the user experience. Therefore you can best achieve a better experience by mapping each field to its value without the need to render the field name in the error.

Form custom rendering will give you full access to the `Form` API, and allow you to display the error in the way you like without the default render, something like the following [looping over form's fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields):

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

By doing the above, you will also need to render the non_field errors, and the complete HTML tags will be as follows:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Django also offers [manual render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for each field something like the following:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.sender.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.cc_myself.id_for_label }}">CC yourself?</label>
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
</div>
```

Choose the best fit for your needs.

---

There is still a hacky thing you can do which is not a best practice and will lead to conflicts between Field validation and non-field validation as follows [Getting a list of errors in a Django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035288/getting-a-list-of-errors-in-a-django-form):

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```